# A 3 point credit is applied to your driving record for a 2-year period

Tags: driving, alberta

Does the following statement mean that the 3 point credit is only good for 2 years and after that the credit points will disappear?

> "[If a Government-approved defensive driving course has been successfully completed prior to accumulating 15 or more points, a 3 point credit is applied to your driving record for a 2-year period.](https://www.alberta.ca/driving-responsibly.aspx)"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what that means.  But if you continue reading the article that you referenced, you will see that demerit points themselves also expire after 2 years:

> When 2 years have passed from the date of a conviction, the demerit
> points assessed for that conviction are removed from your driver's
> record.